# My controller::requestPassAction require that you provide a value for the "$tokengenerator" argument

Tags: symfony

I put in place the functionality of the forgotten password, and for that I ask the user to fill in his email and we send him an email with a token so that he can access a password change form.
And for that I use TokenGeneratorInterface, but it show me this error : controller::requestPassAction require that you provide a value for the "$tokengenerator" argument. Either the argument is nullable and no null value has been provided, no default value has been provided or because there is a non optional argument after this one.

**Controller**

```
   public function requestPassAction(Request $request, TokenGeneratorInterface $tokenGenerator)
{



           $email = $request->request->get('username');

    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($email)
        ->add('username', EmailType::class)
        ->add('save', SubmitType::class, array('label' => 'Envoyer'))
        ->getForm();
    $form->handleRequest($request);


    if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) { 


        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
        $user = $em->getRepository('DoctixUserBundle:User')->loadUserByUsername($form->getData()['username']);
        // ->findOneBy(array('username' => $email));

        if (!$user) {
            $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('warning', "Cet email n'existe pas.");
            return $this->redirectToRoute("renouvellement_pass");
        } 


        $user->setToken($tokenGenerator->generateToken());
        // enregistrement de la date de création du token
        $user->setPasswordRequestedAt(new \Datetime());
        $em->flush();


         $mailer = $this->get('mailer');
    $message = (new \Swift_Message('Renouvellement du mot de passe'))
        ->setFrom("medmamtest@gmail.com")
        ->setTo($user->getUsername())
        ->setBody(
            $this->renderView(
                // app/Resources/views/Emails/registration.html.twig
                'Resetting/request.html.twig',
                array('user' => $user)
            ),
            'text/html'
        );

    $mailer->send($message);
    $request->getSession()->getFlashBag()->add('success', "Un mail va vous être envoyé afin que vous puissiez renouveller votre mot de passe. Le lien que vous recevrez sera valide 24h.");
     return $this->redirectToRoute("login");



    }


    return $this->render('Resetting/request.html.twig', [
        'form' => $form->createView()
    ]);

}
```

And when I initialize the argument to null

```
 public function requestPassAction(Request $request, TokenGeneratorInterface $tokenGenerator = null )
```

I have as error: Call to a member function generateToken() on null in this line :

```
  $user->setToken($tokenGenerator->generateToken());
```

**Information for Service "security.csrf.token_generator"**

```
   Option           Value
---------------- --------------------------------------------
  Service ID       security.csrf.token_generator
  Class        Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenGenerator\UriSafeTokenGenerator
  Tags             -
 Public           no
 Synthetic        no
 Lazy             no
 Shared           yes
 Abstract         no
 Autowired        no
 Autoconfigured   no
```

---

**Services**

```
services:
    _defaults:
        autowire: true


   Doctix\UserBundle\ArgumentResolver\UserValueResolver:
       tags:
           - { name: controller.argument_value_resolver, priority: 50 }


   Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenGenerator\TokenGeneratorInterface: '@security.csrf.token_generator'
```

Thanks

Comment: Check if your autowiring configration for controllers is correct, this is defined in the services.yaml. Which Symfony version are you using?

Comment: https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/controller/argument_value_resolver.html

Comment: Hi @mblaettermann i've checked and my autowiring is true as defined in the documentation.

Comment: should I use the classes present in the configuration mentioned in symfony 3.4 ?

Comment: @MohamedSacko You should probably start by answering the question about which Symfony version is being used.  Makes a big difference.

Comment: Sorry for that, I use symfony 3.4.13

Comment: Okay.  Now from the command line run "bin/console debug:container TokenGeneratorInterface" to confirm the service exists.  I suspect it does not.  You need to have a service with the fully qualified class name for action injection to work.  Probably need to create an alias.

Comment: Ok I do it. And the service exist. I have a service info display

Comment: Hmmm.  You are sure you are looking at the Service ID and not the Class attribute?  Maybe update your question with the results of debug:container. 
 I suppose you could always just pull from the service from the container like you do with the mailer.  But unless you are doing something funky with the way requestPassAction is being called then the token interface implementation should be injected.

Comment: @MohamedSacko does it work with Constructor injection?

Comment: @Cerad i've updated my question with the results of debug:container

Comment: Always glad to be be proven right.  [Read up on service id's and interface aliasing](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/autowiring.html#using-aliases-to-enable-autowiring).  By the way, using the csrf token generator for a password reset token is a bit iffy though it will probably work.

Comment: @mblaettermann I didn't understand the principle of constructor injection. 
that's why I asked you if I had to use the classes in the documentation provided

Comment: Do you have the correct use statements in place?

Comment: @Cerad, I have to choose which section? If I understand correctly I have to create an alias to activate the autowire ?

Comment: @mblaettermann yeah i have the correct use statements in place, and i have the same error.

Answer (score 1):

Guess the hints were not helping.  Just add an alias to your services.yml file

```
# services.yml
Symfony\Component\Security\Csrf\TokenGenerator\TokenGeneratorInterface: '@security.csrf.token_generator'
```

Comment: I've updated my question in adding my services, because I always have the same mistake.